# Did Rachel Scott draw This Picture? and was the Picture dreamt about?

Tags: united-states, esp

Today [Cody Hodges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cody_Hodges#Rachel.27s_Challenge_Work) came to our school and presented [Rachel's Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel%27s_Challenge), named after Rachel Scott, the first student killed in the Columbine High School shooting in 1999.

Hodges claims that, after Rachel's burial on TV, a man called the Scott family saying he had a recurring dream about Rachel crying and a plant being grown when the tears landed.

About a week later the Scott family found [this picture](http://alice24-7.com/SiteImages/Article/4165b.jpg) as her last diary entry. [image]

The picture shows a number of commonalities with the man's dreams, and the thirteen tears predict the number of casualties in the shooting. Hodges went on to say how Rachel often stated that she would die young.

Is there evidence for Rachel drawing this picture and/ for the man to have dreamt that?

Comment: Seems very thin evidenec.

Comment: Who knows? She's dead so we can't ask her, and her having _purportedly_ drawn a creepy picture the night before proves nothing.

Comment: This could possibly be a reasonable question if it were asking if said drawing has been shown to have existed before the shooting took place, but whether it predicted the event, that's unknowable.

Comment: A drawing is not a prediction, nor a claim. If there is a more specific prediction and claim, then please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Edited, not sure exactly how to phrase it. The main question was if there is evidence that the story isn't a scam.